# IntelliJ IDEA Custom VM Options for a specific version?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I updated my IntelliJ IDEA Custom VM Options and now I want to restore these options. So, I need to get  for **v2021.1.2 (build June, 1)** and I am not sure if I can get this config without reinstalling app. Is there any page that listed these options? Or any proper way to get these values?

Comment: You are on Windows AFAIK. Download IDE installer, unpack it (or just use 7Zip to open it) and copy needed files from there. You can also just re-install it (would need to uninstall first: just make that you leave settings in tact, which is by default): it will not overwrite your user/IDE-wide settings (which are stored in your user profile folder).

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about getting these options from a JetBrain page, or revert to default in IntelliJ etc?

Comment: *"What about getting these options from a JetBrain pag"* Sure: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ *"or revert to default in IntelliJ etc"* -- the IDE does not have such functionality (what for?). If installation files are broken/changed by the user (and the bundled VM options file is part of the installation/product itself): re-install it. But you can check https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community -- it *might be* there as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two VM options files: original one <IDE_HOME>\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions and the custom one in IDEA system folder. If you need to restore defaults just copy <IDE_HOME>\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions contents to a custom file. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html.

Comment: It seems to be what I have been looking for. But I am not sure if it has the same content as the previous version of my custom `idea64.exe.vmoptions` before changes. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please specify examples of what can be <IDE_HOME> ? For me the file was : ~/clion-2021.2.1/bin/clion64.vmoptions